# Comparision of mixed effect models via likelihood ratio test and assumption of homogeneity of variance

Tags: mixed-model, likelihood-ratio, heteroscedasticity

I would like compare different models with increasing complexity, since I would like to check the impact of each predictor (and the combination of both predictor variables) on the independent variable Y.
This is roughly what I have executed:

```
Model0 <- lme(Y ~ 1, random = ~ 1 | ID, data = data)
Model1 <- lme(Y ~ A, random = ~ 1 | ID, data = data)
Model2 <- lme(Y ~ A + B, random = ~ 1 | ID, data = data)
Model3 <- lme(Y ~ A * B, random = ~ 1 | ID, data = data)

anova(Model0, Model1, Model2, Model3)
```

However, I have the problem that the baseline model (null model) violates the assumption of homoscedasticity, while the other models meet this assumption. Poses this a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heteroscedasticity problem will affect more the standard errors derived from the model that does not satisfy this assumption.

The likelihood ratio test (LRT) compares the fit of two competing models to the data. For example, you can compare a model that assumes homoscedasticity versus a model that assumes heteroscedasticity. The basic assumptions behind the LRT are that the sample is large enough (such that the test statistic follows the claimed distribution), that the models are nested, and that the null hypothesis does not lie on the boundary of the parameter space.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. This was really helpful. :-)

Comment: @user257053 You are welcome. If you think that this answers your question, you could accept it as a correct/helpful answer.